# how to unmerge a branch in hg/mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branching-and-merging

How do I unmerge/remove a previously added branch from a base branch without deleting the merged branch?

Here is the scenario:

Long back I have merged a branch **(x)** to a base branch **(b)**, since then I have many branches **(y, z, ...)** to **b** and have several commits and pushes. Now I need to remove the changes of **x** from **b** without deleting **b**. So that later if required I can merge that branch again and the changes of **x** are there in b after merge.

Is it possible or do I need to remove my changes in some other branch **(o)**, which will override the changes of **x** in **b**.

Comment: `hg backout` is probably what you're looking for. I'm going to mark this question as a duplicate, because there's another very similar question that should give you the information you need to do what you need without deleting the branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to back out multiple changesets in mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691993/whats-the-best-way-to-back-out-multiple-changesets-in-mercurial)